Conda or Pip build with Variant depending on availability of Gurobi and/or CPLEX
I'm interested in building a conda or package for a binary software whose compilation and run-time execution depends on the availability of external software, namely gurobi and CPLEX.
Gurobi has a conda package that should include binaries, so we could specify the gurobi dependency for that.
However, what about CPLEX?
If the libraries of those dependencies are not found at runtime, my binary cannot start.
Any recommendations?
Many thanks
For context, I've been scouting the variants on conda here:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html
In pip situation is somehow worse as to compile there are bigger dependencies such as build-essentials and alike I'm not really sure they are easy to handle with pip

cplex has a conda package, also on conda-forge

As said at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/ , you have a free community version for CPLEX that you could use so that CPLEX is always available.


Unfortunately that doesn't help.
As a clarification, I need to build 4 variants of the same package depending on the local availability of the solver in the machine of the user not my machine.
I am an academic so I have access to all, but users may only be able to install one of the solvers.
the 4 options are:

no gurobi, no cplex
only gurobi
only cplex
gurobi & cplex

I'd like to build a conda recipe able to:
(a) build such variants
(b) allow the installation of those cases depending on the user

With free CPLEX community edition at least you can be sure you have CPLEX that is available. And that you can replace by a full version if needed
